# Unknown column 'type' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hay Everyone i've got a bit of a problem and just wondering if any of you can help me out.

i'm a bit of a noob when it comes to MySQL and PHP but the problem is i'm geetin a error when i try to add a comment into my Database here is my public function code

```
    public function addComment($movieid, $comment, $user_id)
{
    $comment = stripslashes(strip_tags($comment));
    $comment = mysql_real_escape_string($comment);
    $movieid = mysql_real_escape_string($movieid);
    $user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($user_id);
    if (!($e = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comments WHERE target_id='{$movieid}' AND user_id='{$user_id}' AND comment='{$comment}' AND type=2"))) {
        exit(mysql_error());
    }
    if (mysql_num_rows($e) == 0) {
        if (!($e = mysql_query("INSERT INTO comments(target_id,user_id,comment,date_added,type) VALUES('{$movieid}','{$user_id}','{$comment}',NOW(),2)"))) {
            exit(mysql_error());
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my MySQL comment table Structures

```
 1  id                int(11)                       No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT   
 2  movieid           int(11)                       No  None         
 3  user_id           int(11)                       No  None         
 4  target_id         int(11)                       No  None         
 5  comment           text       utf8_general_ci    No  None         
 6  date_added        datetime                      No  None
```

but i get this error when i try to add a comment

```
Unknown column 'type' in 'where clause'
```

so could someone help help me

thanks

Comment: Doesnt exist `type` colum in your DB table

Comment: where is the column "type" in ur table ?

Comment: Also don't use mysql eh?

Comment: There isno type column in your table, you need to add it first

Comment: why are you using mysql_* functions even if they're deprecated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your table doesn't have a column named `type` . This query will fail. Either you need to add the column `type` to your table or need to change the query to exclude the reference to `type` altogether. What does `type` refer to ?

I want to understand what are you trying to achieve with this query :

> SELECT * FROM comments WHERE target_id='{$movieid}' AND user_id='{$user_id}' 
>       AND comment='{$comment}' **AND type=2**

How will the DB system filter the results when there is no `type` in the table itself ?

Rule of thumb is *First try to execute the query directly over the DB using some IDE or command line , check for the correctness of the query and verify the data as well, before using it in the code* !

Answer (score 0):

You dont have `type` column in your database that is the problem

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly what it says - your table does not have a column named "type". The first mysql_query statement contains `type = '2'` as a condition.
If you remove that part of the statement, it will work - However, I can't judge if the baviour will be correct then :-)

Answer (score 0):

The "type" column is missing from your table.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to this. ( I have removed the `type` column, since it doesn't exist )

```
INSERT INTO comments(target_id,user_id,comment,date_added) VALUES('{$movieid}','{$user_id}','{$comment}',NOW())
```